# Where are installed packages’ dependencies stored?

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

Before installing, a package’s dependencies and conflicts are stored in the control file (of the .deb). Once the package is installed, where are the list its dependencies and conflicts?

I need to remove and then install (not reinstall) [substitute](https://github.com/sbingner/substitute), so I figured that the easiest way to do so without having to remove and then install every package would be to temporarily remove the dependency of substitute from every package, and then do what I need (uninstall and reinstall it).

I’m hoping that if I do this, substitute will begin working. Everything else I’ve tried (manually removing its files and force installing either version 0.1.9 or 0.1.13 with dpkg, downgrading from 0.1.13 to 0.1.9, etc.) hasn’t worked.

Comment: Where did you get the package?

Comment: From Sam Bingner’s repo, https://apt.bingner.com. I would file a issue on substrate’s github page, but for some reason issues are disabled, and I have no other way to reach out about this issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to explain the issues you’re trying to solve. This is on iOS, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. I’ve just found a potential solution (providing that my messing hasn’t screwed up substitute), and am about to try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg` stores its package information, including dependencies, in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Given what you’ve already tried, I doubt removing and installing a package in the way you describe will work any better...

Comment: Thanks; your answer answered my question, and I’ve found a solution to my problem; it turns out that a random tweak was preventing me from starting up properly (when jailbroken)